# My jQuery is not working - I'm trying to insert CSS into elements that have a class attached to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to insert CSS into elements which have a class attached to them, such that I will essentially replace the color of the element to the color inside a list.

It isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {    
    var i = 0,
    colors = ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'purple'];
    function setColor() {
     jQuery('.fc-event-skin').each.eq(i).css('background-color', colors[i  % colors.length]);
          i++;
        if (i == 4) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }})
</script>
```

I rewrote to this, still not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {    
var i = 0,
    colors = ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'purple'];

     jQuery('.fc-event-skin').each(function(i) {
         (this).css('background-color', colors[i  % colors.length]);
          i++;
    if (i == 4) {
        i = 0;
    }
     })
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the relevant code. All you've posted so far are some variables and a function that isn't called by anything.

Comment: setColor() is defined, but never called?

Comment: `(this)` should be `$(this)` or `jQuery(this)`, Check the error console!!!

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, trying to RAPIDLY edit! Haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're doing [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) wrong.

```
$('.fc-event-skin').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(this).css('background-color', colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

Comment: You aren't calling the setColor function, atleast not in the code you have provided. Define "not working". Do some debugging.

Comment: I got rid of setColor, I got rid of all named functions. New code is at the top. Sorry, I'm panicing, I thought this would be simple and I've been using far more time than was allotted to me!

Comment: It would help if you understood how the `each` actually works .  http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: It works! I was an idiot. And yes. I'm still practicing jQuery as opposed to standard JS

Comment: Yes, it is. Let me select it.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.each()` already increments `i` you don't need to do it.  This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   var colors = ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'purple'];

   jQuery('.fc-event-skin').each(function(i) {
       jQuery(this).css('background-color', colors[i]);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way to accomplish this, if anything for learning purposes:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {    
    var colors = ['green', 'red', 'orange', 'brown', 'purple'];
    jQuery('.fc-event-skin').css("background-color",function(i) {
         return colors[i % colors.length];
    });
});
```